# Copy mirrored UV coords doesn't work in Blender 2.82

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Nothing happens after performing the command. The model I was working on is perfectly symmetrical, I know this because I just applied mirror modifier on it. I also did this many times in Blender 2.79 so I know what I'm doing. It also has nothing to do with mesh complexity, boost precision value has no effect, even on something simple as Suzanne. Did this feature somehow changed in 2.82 in some way that needs extra step to do its work? Or is UV function in 2.82 simply not complete, I say this because I also have problem with exporting UV layout which I asked here before?